# ZPL field length - force extra spaces

Tags: zpl

I have a client that is requesting (demanding) that a part number barcode be a specific length:
If the part # is 12 digits, print all 12 in the barcode.  No issue.
If the part # is 10 digits, add trailing spaces. ie "1234567890/space/space/".

Is there a ZPL command that will accomplish this?
I'd rather make the change in ZPL rather than have custom Progress code (QAD ERP) created.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

`ZPL (II)` is just a markup language, like e.g. `HTML`, so unfortunately there are no string formating functions available.